# Angular Universal SSR CRUD App: NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppServerModule)[router_RouterOutlet -> ChildrenOutletContexts]:

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

I'm working on a CRUD app walk through for an Angular Universal with server-side rendering, using MongoDB.  I've done some simple, single page Angular stuff before with forms and validations but this is my first experience with an Angular Universal app w/ a database.

Here are the stats on my angular version, packages, etc being used.  Of note, I use a Macbook and had lots of issues with Angular installing correctly at first.  I used the homebrew package manager to get it to work.

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.26
Node: 12.13.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.14

Package                                    Version
--------------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect                  0.803.26
@angular-devkit/build-angular              0.803.26
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer            0.803.26
@angular-devkit/build-webpack              0.803.26
@angular-devkit/core                       8.3.26
@angular-devkit/schematics                 8.3.26
@angular/cdk                               8.2.3
@angular/cli                               8.3.26
@angular/material                          8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                           8.3.26
@nguniversal/express-engine                8.2.6
@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader   8.2.6
@schematics/angular                        8.3.26
@schematics/update                         0.803.26
rxjs                                       6.4.0
typescript                                 3.5.3
webpack                                    4.39.2
```

I'm able to get it to compile okay using CLI command `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr`

When i open http://localhost:4000/, the page displays this:

```
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[router_RouterOutlet -> ChildrenOutletContexts]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts!
    at NullInjector.get (/Users/dominickdufner/music-app/dist/server/main.js:41980:27)
    at resolveToken (/Users/dominickdufner/music-app/dist/server/main.js:56898:24)
    at tryResolveToken (/Users/dominickdufner/music-app/dist/server/main.js:56824:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (/Users/dominickdufner/music-app/dist/server/main.js:56674:20)
    at resolveToken (/Users/dominickdufner/music-app/dist/server/main.js:56898:24)
    at tryResolveToken (/Users/dominickdufner/music-app/dist/server/main.js:56824:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (/Users/dominickdufner/music-app/dist/server/main.js:56674:20)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (/Users/dominickdufner/music-app/dist/server/main.js:67861:29)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (/Users/dominickdufner/music-app/dist/server/main.js:68927:16)
    at resolveDep (/Users/dominickdufner/music-app/dist/server/main.js:69458:45)
    at createClass (/Users/dominickdufner/music-app/dist/server/main.js:69311:32)
    at createDirectiveInstance (/Users/dominickdufner/music-app/dist/server/main.js:69122:22)
    at createViewNodes (/Users/dominickdufner/music-app/dist/server/main.js:80402:38)
    at callViewAction (/Users/dominickdufner/music-app/dist/server/main.js:80852:13)
    at execComponentViewsAction (/Users/dominickdufner/music-app/dist/server/main.js:80757:13)
    at createViewNodes (/Users/dominickdufner/music-app/dist/server/main.js:80431:5)
```

My command line error also has this at the end:

```
  ngTempTokenPath: null,
  ngTokenPath: [ 'router_RouterOutlet', [Function: ChildrenOutletContexts] ]
```

The browser console out put gives me this:
*"Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:4000/favicon.ico (“default-src”)."*

I've tried the *@NgModule imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]* mentioned in this post in my 'app.module.ts' file but it's not working.

I can add additional file information upon request, or you can check my GitHub repo:
https://github.com/DDufner/Angular-Music-App

Unfortunately I cannot post walk through info due to it having to login to see it. If there is any info that might be helpful I can post it later.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing route config, so in your `app-routing.module.ts` do it like this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: yup, that fixed it!  i kept looking at the 'app.module.ts' file.  thank you for your help!